# dequeueReusableCell... for 2 rows?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

why do we use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier if the cells and section fill exactly the size of the screen, or even less than the height of the screen : let's say we have 2 sections with only 1 row for each?

example :

```
    switch (indexPath.section)
{
    case kMonitoringSection:
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kMonitoringCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kMonitoringCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Monitoring", @"");

            UISwitch *switchCtl = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(197, 8, 94, 27)] autorelease];
            [switchCtl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            switchCtl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

            [cell.contentView addSubview:switchCtl];
        }

        break;
    }

    case kLevelSection:
    {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kLevelCellIdentifier];
        UILabel *levelLabel = nil;
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kLevelCellIdentifier] autorelease];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Level", @"");

            levelLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(171, 11, 120, 21)] autorelease];
            levelLabel.tag = kLevelTag;
            levelLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            [cell.contentView addSubview:levelLabel];
            levelLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        }
```

in the sample code : BatteryStatus

if we had 20 rows, i would understand the point, but i'm not sure here...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have a static number of cells, say only two (different) cells in your tableView and no cell is repeated, you should instead **instanciate your two cells in your XIB** (and design them there with your `UISwitch` for the first one and your custom `UILabel` for the other) **and point an IBOutlet to it**.

Much simpler, less code, and totally makes sense when no reuse of the cells is needed.

**Do read [Apple's Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)** which is a really great resource (like quite every Programming Guide in Apple's doc) and explains all this in details. In particular the part **"[The Technique for Static Row Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW32)"** explains this exact use case.

---

So of course you *can* use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in such case, it won't hurt (and probably in the BatteryStatus sample they did it because they didn't wonder if it was really useful or not, just as an habit because they do this all the time when they have more  rows), but it is not the best way to do it.

Note that sample codes provided by Apple are not always *the* solution to follow: they are just *one* way to do sthg, and especially the sample generally tend to focus on the fonctionnality it wants to test (in this case the Battery Status) and does not worry about anything else (especially performance — except if the sample is about performance of course).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to call it if you don't want to. It isn't a required method or anything like that. The templates put it in for you and many examples use it because it's just there and if you make the table bigger you don't have to add any methods in.

Don't call it if you think you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

It's needlessly wasteful to instantiate a new cell from scratch every time `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, so I would think you'd want to persist your two cells somewhere.

You could do that in any way you want, really, but any general cell caching solution is going to look a lot like `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and any less general solution may get in your way if requirements change.  You're not paying a meaningful performance or readability hit for using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in your example, so why worry about it?